# Is that possible to create a Eclipse plug-in UI (just like a button/menu in Eclipse) to trigger a OSGi platform?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

My Problem is .....

I have a OSGi Software and I try to combine into Eclipse as a plug-in.

Is that possible to create a Eclipse plug-in UI (just like a button/menu in Eclipse) to trigger a OSGi platform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An Eclipse plug-in would allow you to insert the Button feature. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) you have a tutorial, however...

Eclipse is itfself built on top of an OSGi framework: [Equinox](http://eclipse.org/equinox/). Of course, you could embed an OSGi platform such as [Knopflerfish](http://www.knopflerfish.org/) or [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) inside, but this would be a doubtful architecture.

An Eclipse plug-in is itself an OSGi bundle, defined in a standard way with the *MANIFEST.MF* file. In order to complete the standard modularity management feature with an explicit dependency management, Eclipse has its own system relying on the *plugin.xml* file (a kind of glue). You should be able to load all your existing OSGi bundle (non-plug-in) as if these where plugins. If I am not mistaken, the *plugin.xml* file is not required for a plug-in. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/93722/) is an exchange in the Eclipse forum on the topic.